# Can I load a Plugin at cakephp with an alias?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

Let's say that I install a plugin in CakePHP 2.x with name `GmponosCakePlugin`. This plugin would be under Plugins folder with Folder name `GmponosCakePlugin`.

To load the Plugin I need to do the following `CakePlugin::load('GmponosCakePlugin');`

Then if I need to use a Helper from this plugin I would have to use the following syntax `GmponosCakePlugin.MyHelper` inside my AppController in order to load the helper.

Is there any way I could have this plugin alias as `Gmponos` so I could load it as `Gmponos.MyHelper`

Comment: Rename the folder/plugin?

Comment: 1. The plugin is loaded through composer. 2. I could use composer-installer and set a different name for the plugin folder but it is a more complex scenario which is difficult to explain so I thought I might ask if this could be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't rename the folder, then the answer isn't necessarily no, but since there is no explicit plugin name aliasing functionality in CakePHP, all options you have are more or less "hacks".

One option would be for example to register an *additional* fake plugin with the desired name, and a custom path that points to the actual plugin folder, like

```
CakePlugin::load('Gmponos', array (
    'path' => APP . 'Plugin' . DS . 'GmponosCakePlugin' . DS
));
```

This should work (not sure about possible side effects though), but it's kinda ugly. And it should be noted that this is in most cases required *additionally* to registering the normal plugin name, as in the plugin, code will refer to the actual plugin name.

If it's your own plugin, and it is using composer, then changing the install folder name should be pretty easy via the `installer-name` extra option, which is the solution I'd prefer.

**https://github.com/composer/installers#custom-install-names**

You would ofcourse have to change possible plugin name references in the plugin code itself too.

Comment: I will keep that ``there is no explicit plugin name aliasing functionality in CakePHP`` and accept the answer. I have also thought some hacks of my own.. thanks.